# Application lock using device lock

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am working on Xamarin Forms application App lock as i need to secure my app so the app should ask the permission of the device lock when ever we open the application as it can be face lock, pattern, pin, fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin for that.

https://github.com/smstuebe/xamarin-fingerprint

It's pretty simple to use. Please try the 2.0.0 pre release version. It contains the latest features.

```
var result = await CrossFingerprint.Current.AuthenticateAsync("Prove you have fingers!");
if (result.Authenticated)
{
    // do secret stuff :)
}
else
{
    // not allowed to do secret stuff :(
}
```

Comment: Thanks! but If the device using face lock or device does not support finger print in that case?

Comment: same. In some android versions it might not work, because the vendor has a custom API. But if the official API is not used, by the vendor, the auth does not work. Don't be fooled by the name fingerprint plugin. Some years ago, there was no face unlock :)